# Issue with Overriding XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am working on a Chrome extension where I need to intercept and manipulate XMLHttpRequests. To achieve this, I am overriding the `send` method of the `XMLHttpRequest` object. However, I'm facing an issue: the override does not seem to function as expected. When testing the extension, the requests are not being intercepted as they should be.

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

javascript

```
var originalSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

function main() {
    console.log("main function called");

    try {
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
            console.log("XHR send override called");

            this.addEventListener(
                "readystatechange",
                function () {
                    console.log("XHR request state changed:", this.readyState);

                    if (this.responseURL.includes("/api/graphql/") && this.readyState === 4) {
                        console.log("API response received:", this.responseText);
                        // Call to response processing function
                        parseResponse(this.responseText);
                    }
                },
                false
            );
            originalSend.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        // Other functions and logic...
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error executing main:', error);
    }
}

// Other functions like parseResponse, etc.
```

The script is executed as a content script in the extension. When executed, the logs indicate that the main function is being called, but the XMLHttpRequests do not seem to be intercepted as I expect.

Here's what I've already checked:

```
The override of the send method appears to be correct.
The logs in the event listeners show that the function is reached, but the conditions do not seem to match the expected requests.
I am using Manifest V3 for my Chrome extension.
```

I'm wondering if I'm missing something in the way I'm overriding the method or in how XMLHttpRequests are handled in Chrome extensions.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!